# Angular breadcrumb not working on page refresh (ng-route)

Tags: angularjs, breadcrumbs, angularjs-ng-include, ngroute

I've been learning Angular for the past couple of weeks and I've just implemented the breadcrumbs service but it's not working when I refresh the page, or when I first navigate to the page the breadcrumbs exist on. If I return to the home page and then back to the about page, the crumbs work as intended.

Please see [this live example](http://sub.life/angular-breadcrumb-test) of its current state.

I believe it could be the way I'm including the crumbs and that I'm unaware of the rules behind such activities.

The about page has a `ng-include` which grabs the template for the crumbs:

```
<ul id="breadcrumb" ng-controller="crumbCtrl">
  <li><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
  <li ng-repeat="breadcrumb in breadcrumbs.getAll()">
    <ng-switch on="$last"> 
        <span ng-switch-when="true">{{breadcrumb.name}}</span> 
        <span ng-switch-default><a href="{{breadcrumb.path}}">{{breadcrumb.name}}</a></span> 
    </ng-switch>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I do not wish to display the crumbs on the home page for obvious reasons, which is why I have included it only on the about page.

Could someone enlighten me as to a way I should either hide it on the home page only or a correct method of deployment please.

Also, here is my main app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('dunnApp', ['ngRoute', 'services.breadcrumbs']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    // Home
    .when("/", {templateUrl: "partials/home.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
    // Pages
    .when("/about", {templateUrl: "partials/about.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})

    // else 404
    .otherwise("/404", {templateUrl: "partials/404.html", controller: "PageCtrl"});
}]);


angular.module('dunnApp').controller('crumbCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$route', 'breadcrumbs',
  function ($scope, $location, $route, breadcrumbs) {
  $scope.location = $location;
  $scope.breadcrumbs = breadcrumbs;
  console.log("Crumbs online.");
  }]);

app.controller('PageCtrl', function (/* $scope, $location, $http */) {
  console.log("Page Controller online.");


});
```

Comment: event `$routeChangeSuccess` is not triggered on first page load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what happens in your code:

- `breadcrumbs` service is not initialized until `crumbCtrl` gets initialized
- `crumbCtrl` gets into action when `breadcrumbs` template is included to About page.
- In `breadcrumbs` service you listen for `$routeChangeSuccess` events, but this "listener" gets active once the `breadcrumbs` service is initialized, which happens after you navigate to About page once.

So I would suggest you, to place the `$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', ... )` on a place where it will run from the application's startup (eg. in `app.run(function($rootScope)) { ... }`), and add to `breadcrumb` service a `setBreadcrumbs()` function which will be called inside the `$routeChangeSuccess` listener (`breadcrumbs.setBreadcrumbs(result)`).
[Here](http://goo.gl/kQXjIV) is a working version of what I'm suggesting.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, something I will keep in mind. Appreciate your help, Thank you.